# Thumbnails for custom post not showing up in query

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

My thumbnails are not showing up in my custom post type when I do a query, however they show in the `single.php` file.

I have added `'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')` to the function so I know its not that issue. I am gettin the rest of the data on the query as viewable below but the image should be above the text:
[image]

I am not having this issue in the single page with the featured image showing up :

[image]

I am registering my custom post type as so:

```
add_action('init', 'video_custom_init');    

/* SECTION - video_custom_init */
function video_custom_init()
{
    // the remainder code goes here
}
/* #end SECTION - video_custom_init --*/

// The following is all the names, in our tutorial, we use "video"
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('videos', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('video', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'video'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New video'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit video'),
        'new_item' => __('New video'),
        'view_item' => __('View video'),
        'search_items' => __('Search videos'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No videos found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No videos found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'video'
    );

    // Some arguments and in the last line 'supports', we say to WordPress what features are supported on the video post type
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
    );

    // We call this function to register the custom post type
    register_post_type('video',$args);
```

I am pretty confused about what the issue would be. It is probably something really simple.

Query used to display custom post.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'video', 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

                    get_template_part( '/templates/content-3col');

                    endwhile;?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

and the code in col3.php

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="page-header" style="border-bottom:none; margin-bottom:0;">
        <?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>
        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail('col-6-thumb');

                } ?>
        </a>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
            </header>


        <div class="article-info">
        <div class="article-date"><h3><?php the_time('M jS') ?></h3></div>
        <div class="articletitle"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><p>by <?php the_author() ?></p></div>
                </div>  
    </article><!-- #post-## --> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for the query you are using to display on the front end ? Not the single page code.

Comment: @Subharanjan added above

Comment: Can you please show me the code for get_template_part( '/templates/content-3col'); themplate file ?? :)

Comment: @Subharanjan opps sorry, added above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <header class="page-header" style="border-bottom:none; margin-bottom:0;">
            <div style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
                <?php   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail('col-6-thumb');
                } ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="article-info">
            <div class="article-date"><h3><?php the_time('M jS') ?></h3></div>
            <div class="articletitle"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><p>by <?php the_author() ?></p></div>
        </div>  
    </article><!-- #post-## --> 
</div>
```

Can you put this code inside the template file that your including using `get_template_part( '/templates/content-3col');`

**Note:** As you are querying for post type "video", you should check for post type as "video" instead. Here you are checking for "post" `<?php if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) : ?>` which was causing the problem. I have just removed that.

Comment: brillant. It works. It was a silly mistake by me. Thanks Subharanjan. Ill accept ur answer when the time limit runs out

Comment: after note section you answer is complete now.

Comment: @Ravs: Thanks !! By the time I got the edit suggestion, I had already added the note. :)